# Writing to another python program's raw input without popping a new black screen

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, stdin

I am trying to brute-force a python program:
what I need is to make another python file that will run
the first python code with an input (The first code takes input with raw_input)

The problem is that the first code uses pygame, so if I want to brute-force I need to run it, try a number, then open it again, and continue checking like that...
do you have any idea how to write to a process raw_input like a bruteforce?

This is a lite version of what I'm trying to do: (without pygame)

first code: (The one I need to bruteforce)

```
found = []
while 1:


    a =int(raw_input("ENTER : "))
    print "THE NUM: ", a
    if a in [74,82,101,550,990]:
        print a , "  Got number right!"
        found.append(a)

    if [74,82,101,550,990] == found:
        print "WINNER!!!!!"
        break
```

This one does not have pygame, but the idea stays the same..

I tried using this code:

```
import subprocess
for i in range(1000):
    process = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "PATH TO PYCODE"], 
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.stdin.write(i)
    print process.communicate()[0]
    process.stdin.close()
```

But it gives this error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

and the path is 100% correct...

Edit:
if I write in cmd:

```
echo 5 | python PATH_TO_FILE
```

it pops this error:

```
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Thanks for helping! :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  On this site it's important to focus on one problem at a time, and we should start with the second issue: the first python program isn't working.  You are getting the end-of-file because you're in an infinite loop reading from standard input, but you didn't supply an infinite amount of input.  Presumably it first prints "ENTER : THE NUM : 5", which is what I get when I run it. You need a way to detect the end of input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues.

First, the top program (which I'll call check.py) doesn't terminate on EOF, it throws an error.  Second, the top program is written to be interactive but you're using it noninteractively.  Removing the "INPUT : " should be enough to fix this for your purposes.

Try this:

```
import sys
found = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip();

    a = int(line);
    print "THE NUM: ", a
    if a in [74,82,101,550,990]:
        print a , "  Got number right!"
        found.append(a)

    if [74,82,101,550,990] == found:
        print "WINNER!!!!!"
        break
```

Third, the bottom program will never be the WINNER because it restarts the program for each guess.  Fourth, you're writing binary values into the pipe, but your program expects text.

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "check.py"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for i in range(1000):
    process.stdin.write("%d\n" % i)
print process.communicate()[0]
process.stdin.close()
```

Before running this you probably want to delete "THE NUM" printout from check.py.

However, your initial question did say that you need to restart the pygame each time, so in that case you would leave the loop on `i` as you had it originally -- that's just not what your example program is written to expect.

Here's the output, with the "THE NUM : " output commented out:

```
$ python pipe.py
74   Got number right!
82   Got number right!
101   Got number right!
550   Got number right!
990   Got number right!
WINNER!!!!!
```